# I have a list of dictionaries (json) with html formatting in one of key value, is there any way to conv it to xml with html format?

Tags: python, html, json, excel, pandas

Here is part of json:

```
[{
"notificationMessageTemplate POZYTYWNY": "1035_WIADOMOSC_KROK_ZAKONCZONY_SUKCESEM",
"treść komunikatu POZYTYWNY": "<p>Szanowni Państwo,<br>informujemy, że zadanie:<br><br><b>Weryfikacja możliwości naliczania rezerw NUR w BOS (potwierdzenie, że sumy kontrolne dotyczące rezerw NUR są zatwierdzone)</b><br></p><p><br><span style=\"color: rgb(33,130,80);
},
{notificationMessageTemplate NEGATYWNY: "","treść komunikatu POZYTYWNY": ""

}]
```

It's just a part of whole list of dicts in json, I want to add whole list to excel file, result it's okay but i want [treść komunikatu POZYTYWNY] = [value] in excel file with html formatting, not with whole html signs etc.
For saving json as an excel file im using 'to_excel' from pandas.

Here is view from excel file:
[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4LKG.png)